# Find the minimal constant $k$ :$\frac{a+k}{a+bc}+\frac{b+k}{b+ca}+\frac{c+k}{c+ab}\ge 3k+2,$ holds $ab+bc+ca=1.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, symmetric-polynomials, uvw

> **Problem.** Find the minimal constant $k$ sastisfying $$\frac{a+k}{a+bc}+\frac{b+k}{b+ca}+\frac{c+k}{c+ab}\ge 3k+2,$$holds for all $a,b,c: ab+bc+ca=1.$

---

I've tried more but there is no good approach. Equality holds at $(0,1,1).$

We can rewrite the OP as $$k\left(\frac{1}{a+bc}+\frac{1}{b+ca}+\frac{1}{c+ab}-3\right)\ge 2-\frac{a}{a+bc}-\frac{b}{b+ca}-\frac{c}{c+ab}.$$
I saw that by Cauchy-Schwarz $$2-\frac{a}{a+bc}-\frac{b}{b+ca}-\frac{c}{c+ab}=\frac{bc}{a+bc}+\frac{ca}{b+ca}+\frac{ab}{c+ab}-1,$$
$$\ge \frac{(ab+bc+ca)^2}{(ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ca)^2+3abc}=\frac{abc(2a+2b+2c-3abc)}{(ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ca)^2+3abc}\ge 0,$$which is true since $a+b+c\ge \sqrt{3}.$

Hence $k=0$ is chosen. For the remain, I think we should consider $$Q=\frac{1}{a+bc}+\frac{1}{b+ca}+\frac{1}{c+ab}-3.$$
If $Q>0$ then the desired $k$ is positive.
If $Q<0$ then the desired $k$ is negative.

> I stopped here. Is my approach is possible? Hope to see others idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some thoughts.**

Thanks to above Michael Rozenberg's hint, I write a proof. Hope to see responses.

The original inequality $$\frac{a+k}{a+bc}+\frac{b+k}{b+ca}+\frac{c+k}{c+ab}\ge 3k+2. \tag{*}$$

We can rewrite the $(*)$ as
$$k\left(\frac{1}{a+bc}+\frac{1}{b+ca}+\frac{1}{c+ab}-3\right)\ge 2-\frac{a}{a+bc}-\frac{b}{b+ca}-\frac{c}{c+ab}.$$
By using Cauchy-Schwarz $$2-\frac{a}{a+bc}-\frac{b}{b+ca}-\frac{c}{c+ab}=\frac{bc}{a+bc}+\frac{ca}{b+ca}+\frac{ab}{c+ab}-1,$$
$$\ge \frac{(ab+bc+ca)^2}{(ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ca)^2+3abc}=\frac{abc(2a+2b+2c-3abc)}{(ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ca)^2+3abc}\ge 0,$$
which is true since $a+b+c\ge \sqrt{3}.$

We will prove $\boxed{k\ge 0.}$

Hence, it is enough to prove
$$\frac{1}{a+bc}+\frac{1}{b+ca}+\frac{1}{c+ab}\ge 3.\tag{1}$$
*Proof*

Let $a+b+c=3u, ab+bc+ca=3v^2,abc=w^3.$ The $(1)$ turns out $$f(w^3)=-3w^6+A(u,v^2)w^3+B(u,v^2)\ge 0.$$
It is $f''(w^3)=-3<0.$

Hence, $f(w^3)$ is concave which $uvw$ says that we only need to prove $(1)$ is true when $w^3$ get extremal value.

We'll check in two cases

- $w^3=0.$ Let $a=0, bc=1$ and $(1)$ becomes $$\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\ge 2,$$which is true by AM-GM.
- Two equal variables. Let $0<b=c=x\le 1; a=\dfrac{1-x^2}{2x}.$ By some calculating works, we can rewrite $(1)$ as
  $$\frac{(x-1)(x^2 - 2 x - 1)\left(x^4-\dfrac{3x^3}{2}-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{1}{6}\right)}{x}\le 0,$$ which is true by $0<x\le 1.$

Hence, $(1)$ is proven.

In next part of proof, we will find $k\ge 0$ sastifying the following is true
$$k\ge \frac{2-\dfrac{a}{a+bc}-\dfrac{b}{b+ca}-\dfrac{c}{c+ab}}{\dfrac{1}{a+bc}+\dfrac{1}{b+ca}+\dfrac{1}{c+ab}-3}.\tag{**}$$
Now, we will prove **the claim** that: "It is enough to prove $(*)$ when either $abc=0$ or two equal variables.(2)"

Indeed, rewrite $(*)$ as $$g(w^3)=-(3k+2)w^6+A(u,v^2)w^3+B(u,v^2)\ge 0.$$
It is $g''(w^3)=-3k-2<0$ since $k\ge 0.$

Hence, $g(w^3)$ is concave which $uvw$ says that we only need to prove $(*)$ is true when $w^3$ get extremal value.

The claim $(2)$ is proven.

Finally, let $0<b=c=x\le 1; a=\dfrac{1-x^2}{2x}.$ We will find $k_0\ge 0$ such that$$k_0=\text{max} \frac{2-\dfrac{\dfrac{1-x^2}{2x}}{\dfrac{1-x^2}{2x}+x^2}-\dfrac{x}{x+x\dfrac{1-x^2}{2x}}-\dfrac{x}{x+x\dfrac{1-x^2}{2x}} }{\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1-x^2}{2x}+x^2}+\dfrac{1}{x+x\dfrac{1-x^2}{2x}}+\dfrac{1}{x+x\dfrac{1-x^2}{2x}}-3} , x\in(0;1].$$
(In case $w^3=0$ we get $k\ge 0.$)

By [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=max%5C%28123%29Divide%5B2-Divide%5BDivide%5B1-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2C2x%5D%2CDivide%5B1-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2C2x%5D%2BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D-Divide%5Bx%2Cx%2BxDivide%5B1-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2C2x%5D%5D-Divide%5Bx%2Cx%2BxDivide%5B1-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2C2x%5D%5D%2CDivide%5B1%2CDivide%5B1-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2C2x%5D%2BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%2BDivide%5B1%2Cx%2BxDivide%5B1-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2C2x%5D%5D%2BDivide%5B1%2Cx%2BxDivide%5B1-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%2C2x%5D%5D-3%5D%5C%28125%29) assiting, we obtain the answer $\boxed{k\ge k_0\approx 1.2364.}$

*Notice that*

When $k=k_0,$ equality holds also at $(0,0.1671,0.1671).$

About $uvw,$ see also [here.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3335587h278791_the_uvwmethod?fbclid=IwAR0M6dAGu5XNuBUj8UvaQwmLSP-jIsXG_OEmZHUfyU5unz_TY4P7njEeqgg)

Comment: -1, It is not a proof. Let give full step proof.

Comment: @Dragonboy I will update it soon. I have not find a good tool to make proof clearly

Answer (score 0):

It means, of course, that our variables are non-negative.

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, your inequality is equivalent to $$-(3k+2)w^6+A(u,v^2)w^3+B(u,v^2)\geq0,$$ which is concave function of $w^3$.

Thus, by $uvw$ it's remains to check to cases:

1. $w^3=0$;
2. Two variables are equal.

Can you end it now?

Comment: +1, thanks for your hint. I am feel a little confusing about "your inequality is equivalent to $$-(3k+2)w^6+A(u,v^2)w^3+B(u,v^2)\geq0,$$ which is concave function of $w^3$."
What does $A(u,v^2)w^3,B(u,v^2)$ mean ? I've acquaint to function recently. How did you prove it is concave function? 
(Sorry for my bad knowledges. With your help, I will try to research more.)

Comment: A and B are functions of $u$ and $v^2$

Comment: Is that a short cut form instead of giving full expanding yields ? By the way, I've calculated 
$f'(w^3)=-2(3k+2)w^3+A(u,v^2).$ The second derivative is  $f''(w^3)=[f'(w^3)]'=-2(3k+2)<0.$ 
Is it right ?

Comment: Yes. It says that $f$ is a conclave function and gets a minimal value for an extreme value of $w^3$

Comment: To continue it, I think we prove the inequality is true in two cases:
1. $w^3=0$ which is obvious.
2. $0<b=c=x\le 1; a=\dfrac{1-x^2}{2x}$. 
In my opinion, we need to full expand the expression $−(3k+2)w^6+A(u,v^2)w3+B(u,v^2)\ge 0$ because $A(u,v^2),B(u,v^2)$ includes $k.$
For the remain, we can rewrite $k.Q(x)\ge P(x) \iff k\ge \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}$ and
$k_0=max  \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}$ on $(0;1]$ is desired value.
Is my approach resonable?

Comment: Later I'll write a full solution. Just I am very busy now.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I think $3k+2\ge 0$

Comment: @Dragon boy Which says we have a concave function of $w^3$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg How about $k<-\dfrac{2}{3}$ ?

Comment: @Dragon boy We can prove that $k\geq0$. For example, see the TATA box's post.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Is my proof  eligible ?

Comment: @TATA box I think, your reasoning is right. I checked it yesterday.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks. If it is available for you, I hope you share proof to us. In my proof, there is some bad points

Comment: @TATA box I'll check it again later.

Comment: I think your answer is worth to accept. You could update it for detail proof later.